# Binary tree to list in post-order in racket

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, binary-tree, racket, postorder

Hi I am trying to transfer a binary tree to a list but crossing it in post-order.

```
(define (postorden arbol)
  (if (null? arbol) 
    ('()) (append (append (postorden (car (cdr arbol))) 
                          (postorden (car (cddr arbol)))) 
                  (list (car arbol)))))
```

But I get this error:

cdr: contract violation
   expected: pair?
   given: 'null

But for example with this tree: '((1 2) ((7 10) ((2 4) null null)) ((6 8) ((10 13) null null) null))

performed the cdr and get: (((7 10) ((2 4) null null)) ((6 8) ((10 13) null nul) null))
and then I make the car to this outcome: '((7 10) ((2 4) null null)) which if it is a pair. So I do not understand what is wrong.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

An `if` expression has the for `(if e0 e1 e2)` where e0,e1,and,e2 are expressions.
In your program you have:

```
(if e0
    ('() ...)
    e2)
```

This means that if e0 is true, then `('() ...)` is evaluated.

Here `'()` is the empty list also known as `null`.

The expression `('() ...)` will attempt to call `'()` with the result of `...`,
and thus give an error.

Fix this error, and hopefully your other errors disappears - if not show us what you've and ask again.